# Propagation of a Gaussian beam using FFT

Tags: optics, waves, computational-physics, fourier-transform, software

I am trying to simulate the propagation of a gaussian beam through a lens using an FFT approach.

I tried to implement the approach described by Couairon in this paper at page 43: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjst/e2011-01503-3

Here is a description of the algorithm: 
[image: The algorithm]
However, when I propagate the beam from a lens to the focal spot and then past it, the amplitude $|E|$ on the axis I get is much less than if the theoretical amplitude that I can compute using the theoretical formulas(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam).

Here is how the intensity evolves:

[image: Evolution of the on axis (r=0) amplitude of the beam]
[image: Beam profile at the focal plane]

It seems to me that there is a missing «scaling parameters» that needs to be included? Any idea what is missing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s about debugging a code rather than the physics of the problem.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, at this point, it is unclear to me wether the problem is related to the physics and the formulas that I use or the code... It is not strictly about debugging code.

Comment: *Do you see anything wrong in my implementation of the algorithm?* Seems to be strictly about debugging code....

Comment: I modified the question to make it more physics-based and less about the code. Please help.